# Rogue Wave Edit Box text

Tags: c++, rogue-wave

I want to check if the Text box has some text entered by the user but can't. The statement below always returns false

```
if (MyLLVTextEdit->getMessage() == NULL)
{
    MessageBox(NULL,"No Text", "no Text",NULL);
}
```

also tried

```
if (MyLLVTextEdit->getMessage() == "")
{
    MessageBox(NULL,"No Text", "no Text",NULL);
}


if (MyLLVTextEdit->getValue() == NULL)
{
    MessageBox(NULL,"No Text", "no Text",NULL);
}

if (MyLLVTextEdit->getValue() == "")
{
    MessageBox(NULL,"No Text", "no Text",NULL);
}
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Does Rogue Wave provide GUI-library meanwhile? I used to know it as one of STL-implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't familiar with your library, but you should use `strcmp` function to compare strings (char*), to check if string is empty, you may call `strlen`

```
strlen(MyLLVTextEdit->getMessage()) == 0
```

`operator==` may be used only if you use some string classes like `std::string` `QString` or whatever

Answer (score -2):

What does getMessage() return? Very unlikely char*, as Rogue Wave has own unicode-capable string classes.

If it a kind of a Rogue Wave string-class, check if there is a method for testing the content for emptiness.

Probably you should use something like:

```
if (MyLLVTextEdit->getMessage().isNull() )
```

or

```
if (MyLLVTextEdit->getMessage().isEmpty() )
```